# How to determine the best model based on ROC curves

Tags: machine-learning, roc

I have created four models of Logistic Regression (binary classification) and have developed the ROC curves of those 4 models.
However, I am not able to understand how to scientifically determine the best model of the four and thereby finalize the best model of the four.
I request someone to kindly help me out with determining the best reasoning to finalize the best model.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through some basics first and then expose the relevant information that the plot is conveying.

---

The `ROC` curves are giving you a measure on the degree of separability of both classes by a model, that is, how well it can distinguish both classes. The curves that you see represent the respective `TPR` and `FPR` (or percentages in your case) obtained by a model at different thresholds.

Understanding the role *thresholds* play here is important;
In order to compute the ROC curves, we need the probabilities output by the model, since the goodness of classification (measured in terms of `TPR`vs`FPR`) will be computed for different thresholds. Take for instance that the model is giving you a `0.8` probability. By using a `0.5` threshold, the sample would be classified as a `1`, but instead it would be classified as a `0` with a `0.85` threshold. Checking the results through the corresponding metrics will result in a different *point* in the curve.

The entire `ROC` curve of a classifier will be obtained by repeating the above, that is, computing the `TPR` and `FPR`, on different thresholds until you get a line describing the general *behaviour* of the classifier.

> But why do I need to know how well it classifies on `thresholds!=0.5`? You may ask...

This will be telling you how good a classifier predicts in scenarios where you might not be all that interested in the best `AUC`, but perhaps rather be more flexible with your `FPR` for example (meaning going towards the right side of the graph, and getting a better `TPR`).

In that case you might want to compare the response of the different models at thresholds which have led to a higher `TPR` (at the expense of a lower `FPR`, and hence `AUC` score). This will most likely **not** be occurring at a `0.5` threshold, and you'll have to see what the response is at different thresholds to see the setting that suits you the most.

In the general case, in which you want to minimise the mis-classification of both classes in a *balanced* way, the optimal threshold will the the one closer to the upper left corner, or in other words the one which results in a higher distance to the diagonal line (the diagonal line just represents the point at which a classifier does not know how to distinguish among both classes).

But as mentioned, what makes the `ROC` curve so useful is that it tells you what is the goodness of classification of your model *depending on what metrics you want to *prioritise*

So to summarise, the information we can obtain from a `ROC` curve as:

- What is the best threshold for each of the classifiers
- Which classifier behaves better overall

So essentially we can see it as a *picture* of how well a classifier behaves on different scenarios that might be of more or less interest according to each problem.

Comment: Thank you Yatu for your response. Helped me a lot.